# php and mysql - updating longblob field not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Im trying to update a field in a row in one of the tables in my schema and Im not getting any errors in my php log but the value doesnt update into the field. I have my update query written like this:

```
$dbQuery00 = "UPDATE `billing`.`sale_transaction` SET `Signature` = '$signatureUpload'  WHERE `TRANSCODE` = '$transID';";
$result = mysqli_query($dbObj,$dbQuery00) or trigger_error('Failed on dbQuery00'.mysqli_error(), mysqli_errno());
```

When I post the $result variable to the error_log it shows the correct number of fields that should have been updated which is just one but nothing shows.

The value that Im updating is a png file and Im inserting it into a longblob field. I have the similar set up working in other places but for some reason this particular little update query is a no go.....any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `$transID` is what you expected (that is, you're updating then checking the row you expect)? `$result` is only going to be true or false here, not a number of fields updated.

Comment: hmmmm.....yes Ive posted the transID to the error_log and its what it should be. Let me run my script once again to see what comes up in the error log again.

Comment: ok so the signature value comes out as "Array" and the result value comes out as 1. I suppose I should add that I cast both to (string) inorder to see them in the error log

Comment: Do not give `mysqli_errno()` in the second parameter of `trigger_error()`.... `mysqli` error numbers have nothing to do with php error numbers. Depending on desired behavior, use `E_USER_ERROR` (fatal), `E_USER_WARNING` (severe) or `E_USER_NOTICE`(well, notice it is ;) ).

Comment: Thanks for replying but I dont really have a problem with the error catching. My problem is that the data I send to my script doesnt make it into the table im trying to update. I dont see any errors related to the data so Im kind of stuck

Comment: If `$signatureUpload` is an array then you can't just stick it into your query. Your PNG file is not an array. I can't tell you what the code should be from just this snippet.

Comment: Ok so I was finally able to get my data to insert into the table but when I try to view it in the mysql workbench it doesnt show up as an image. The text value says array and the binary value only has 5 spaces taken up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok turns out I had to use the following code to allow the png file to be updated into my mysql table.

```
$imgData = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["signatureUpload"]["tmp_name"]));
```

That little bit of code allowed me to take posted data to my script and update the image in the table.